# Unable to write data to Firebase real-time database with Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have installed Firebase/Database in my cocoa pods, configured it in my AppDelegate, imported my Google plist, turned the read and write permission to true, and in viewDidLoad(), I wrote

```
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
rootRef.child("users").setValue(["name": "Ryan"])

rootRef.child("users").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
}
```

The thing is, it prints out the

```
Snap (users) {
    username = Ryan;
}
```

However, I don't see the change in my real-time database, so if I get rid of

```
rootRef.child("users").setValue(["name": "Ryan"])
```

and rerun the program, nothing comes out.

In my database, if I add a key-value pair under my root directory, like "Yo": "hey"[image]

And do an observe event with

```
rootRef.child("yo").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
}
```

Nothing comes out again

I am pretty sure my firebase service is connected because my user authentication works, but my database doesn't. Can someone please help me!

Comment: this `rootRef.child("users").setValue(["name": "Ryan"])` is not getting added to the db?

Comment: Apparently ya. I don't know why. I don't see it in the database, even after refreshing, if I print the `rootRef.child("users").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in print(snapshot) }` out immediately then I can see the values, but if I delete that line and rerun the program, I see nothing coming out.

Comment: Most likely cause is that you don't have permission to read from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not a child.

`["yo":"hey"]` is a dictionary data structure.
Code:

```
rootRef.child("loginwithgooddesignpractice").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you may be having might stem from understanding the structure of the Firebase database. In your case the root is well referenced, however from there it is not well organized. to create a root/users/id/yo:"hey" structure I suggest writing it as:

```
   rootRef.child("users").childByAutoId().setValue("hey", forKey: "yo")
```

This way puts the users as a dictionary which will hold multiple unique id's of other users which is another dictionary holding the value yo:"hey".